# Are all other religions after islam are fraud?

Tags: other-religions, monotheism

Prophet muhammad saw is the last prophet sent by Allah so that means all other people who preach after his death are fraud and all other religions that came after his death are also fraud?

Comment: Yes, you got it

Comment: That's a big statement to make though..

Comment: Well, do you think it's logical that Islam agrees that other religions are true ? Doesn't *every* religion say "I am the truth, believe in me, and only me"?

Comment: No..other religions don't say that..

Comment: They do… otherwise they aren’t religions, just philosophy

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Absolutely based on below evidence.

> It is He Who has sent His Messenger (ﷺ) with guidance and the religion
> of truth (Islam), to make it **superior over all religions** even though
> the Mushrikun (polytheists, pagans, idolaters, disbelievers in the
> Oneness of Allah) hate (it). Quran (9:33)
>
> And whoever seeks a **religion other than Islam**, it will never be
> accepted of him, and in the Hereafter he will be one of the losers.
> Quran (3:85)